# Program take the non null child and proceed operations with it

Tags: java, inheritance

I have created three child classes based on a parent class.

While my program is running, one of the child classes will be instantiated, and I have some operations that would require the non null child object.

Here are some examples of my code:

Parent:

```
public class Person {
     // code here
     doMore(Operation operation) {
          //code here
     }
}
```

Operation class:

```
public class Operation {

     Person person;

     public Operation(Person person) {
          this.person = person;
     }
}
```

Child classes:

```
public class Doctor extends Person {
     // code here
}

public class Lawyer extends Person {
     // code here
}

public class Pilot extends Person {
     // code here
}
```

Main program:

```
// String temp is calculated 

Doctor doctor = null;
Lawyer lawyer = null;
Pilot pilot = null;

if (temp.equals("doctor")) {
     doctor = new Doctor();
     Operation operation = new Operation(doctor);
     doctor.doMore(operation);
} else if (temp.equals("lawyer")) {
     lawyer = new Lawyer();
     Operation operation = new Operation(lawyer);
     lawyer.doMore(operation);
} else {
     pilot = new Pilot();
     Operation operation = new Operation(Pilot);
     pilot.doMore(operation);
}
```

As you can see, depending on the value of temp, only one of the three child classes will be instantiated and only one of the objects will be non null.

I have two more operations that after instantiation that will use the newly created object.  Right now, repeating the same two lines three times seems redundant.

Is there a way to simplify this so the two lines are only used once?  Is there some feature of inheritance that I can use here?

Comment: Alot depends on definition of `Operation` class.

Comment: @tsolakp Thanks. It is added as well to my post.

Comment: `temp = "doctor"` will always return a truthy value (it's an assignment). You should probably be using `temp.equals("doctor")`, which actually does the string comparison.

Comment: @alephtwo good catch.  I have modified it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is, in fact, actually pretty simple. While it's not how I would personally write the code, you can get your desired result by doing something like the following:

```
Person person = null;

if (temp.equals("doctor")) {
  person = new Doctor();
} else if (temp.equals("lawyer")) {
  person = new Lawyer();
} else {
  person = new Pilot();
}

Operation operation = new Operation(person);
person.doMore(operation);
```

Since `Person` is an interface that all three classes implement, you can treat all of them as a `Person`.

For what it's worth, I would write an `enum` to encapsulate the strings you're comparing against and write a `switch` statement. That said, you can also `switch` on strings:

```
switch (temp) {
  case "doctor": break;
  case "lawyer": break;
  default: break;
}
```

Comment: In addition, you could move the ifs to a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)), if you want. Then you'd have `Person person = createPerson(temp); ...`

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I was wondering though, if Person is an abstract class, could I still do something like this?

Comment: You can, provided that `Doctor` etc. all extend `Person`.